# MySQL select a column with replaced text where it equals a value

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdo, gmail

I was recently alerted to the fact that gmail email addresses are the same whether you put a "." before "@gmail.com". So "myemail@gmail.com" and "my.email@gmail.com" both send to the "myemail@gmail.com".

As a result, when users sign up on my website, I want to check that they aren't using this exploit to make multiple accounts with essentially the same email address.

I sanitize the email address they send me, log into my database with PDO and then try running this code:

```
$data=$db->query("SELECT REPLACE(email,'.','') AS email_without_periods FROM account_data HAVING email_without_periods LIKE '".str_replace($sanitizedEmail,".","")."'");

if($row=$data->fetch()){
//It found a match between the sanitized email without decimals and the email rows without decimals. Hey, this dude's trying to create multiple accounts!
    $error="You're trying the email decimal trick! You sneaky devil... ";
}
```

However, this input doesn't work: it doesn't seem to register any rows.

When I replaced `LIKE '".str_replace($sanitizedEmail,".","")."'"` with `LIKE '%".str_replace($sanitizedEmail,".","")."%'"`, it brought back *all* of the rows.

I basically want to search for `str_replace($postEmail,".","")` in the database, but to remove all the periods in `email` rows first. I'm using PDO.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the value of `$sanitizedEmail`?

Comment: Since you're using PDO, why aren't you using prepared statements instead of concatenating into the SQL?

Comment: You're replacing all the periods with commas, not removing them. Use `replace(email, ',', '')` to remove them. But you're also removing the period in `gmail.com`, so it will become `gmailcom`.

Comment: `$sanitizedEmail` might be `myemail@gmail.com"` Basically any email address that the form gets with `$_POST` and then sanitizes.

Comment: So if the user enters `my.email` in the form, you'll sanitize it to `myemail`?

Comment: I hope you only do this for `gmail.com`. Other sites don't necessarily ignore the period.

Comment: I don't have a problem using prepared statements, but I didn't think it was a security issue in this case. If I'm wrong though, please let me know!

I notice that you added spaces in your `replace` statement after the second and last comma, does that affect the resulting code?

Yep, all periods are removed in both cases. But they'll all read the same anyway, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: I didn't add a space, I just wrote `''` -- two quotes right next to each other.

Comment: I wasn't sure if any other email clients did the same, and figured that the odds were low enough that two people would come in with two different email addresses separated by a period for it to be a concern. If I can know for a fact that gmail's the only mailing service that works this way, I don't have any problem making it gmail-specific.

Comment: I'm double-checking my code, it looks the same but without the spaces and lower-case `replace`. `REPLACE(email,'.','')`. I accidentally posted before I was finished and went back and tweaked it, maybe you saw an old typo?

Comment: Many other sites allow `account+xxx@domain.com`, where `+xxx` is ignore when finding the account -- it allows users to filter emails into folders automatically. So `account+x` and `account+y` are the same account. And people can also just create multiple email accounts. I think you'll drive yourself crazy trying to detect all the duplicates.

Comment: You're right, I misread the original code, I thought the comma was inside the quotes.

Comment: The function for sanitizating doesn't look at the periods, I only remove the periods for this check. Sanitization takes place before this query.

Before this check, I also look for an exact match with all of the periods and send a separate message letting the user know they already have an account (so if somebody's email address is my.mail@aol.com, it doesn't make it mymail@aol.com before creating their account; if it did, it would mess with them receiving emails with aol).

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of the `+` option, I'll look into that. If it's unreasonable to block all the possibilities, I'm willing to step down. I'm looking into this because a user pointed it out to me (that said, they are a friend who wouldn't exploit it themselves).

Comment: Users get points for referring other users; that's why I'm trying to block users from having multiple accounts. I don't want them referring themselves. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments in the wrong order in `str_replace`. It should be:

```
str_replace('.', '', $sanitizedEmail)
```

You were using the same argument order as SQL's `REPLACE` function, but they're different.